# Why not found timestamp field after index a document In ElasticSearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use Java Low Level REST Client to put documents with es 5.3.

`restClient.performRequest("PUT", esPath, Collections.emptyMap(), entity, new Header[0]);`

And it succeed to insert.

But I can't find timestamp field in `_source` of the response.

***Edit***
The entity is a json string

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggQEN.jpg)

Comment: Maybe show how `entity` looks like....

Comment: @Val It is a json string.

Comment: Well, you have no date or timestamp in there, ES won't add any timestamp for you